# Is it possible to run two iterative equations in the same forloop?

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I'm running into an issue within my forloop. My goal of this loop is to create a matrix that follows equation 1 for the first column of the matrix (:,1) and follows equation 2 for the rest of the matrix (2,end-1). The matrix is a 201x211 matrix. I'm using a laplace approach and starting with an initial guess of zero across the matrix (that is why my h variable is starting off as a zero matrix). Beta 1 and beta 2 are constant matrixes of 0.25 and beta 3 and beta 4 are constant matrixes of 0.5. My boundaries are 0 (row 1, h(1,:)=0) and 5 (row 201, ny1=201 and coded as h(ny1,:)=Inlet pressure where inlet pressure is 5). Would this be possible to create a matrix with two iterative equations, or will I have to change my approach? I noticed partly with the error that the head calculation will go to infinity or negative infinity as well. Attached are the two equations being used.

```
% Calculating Pressure Head 
h = zeros([ny1 nx1]); %h is pressure head units of mm
w = 1.8; %constant for SOR Method

for it = 1:niter
    hn = h;
    h(i,j) = ((1-w)*hn(i,j))+(w*((beta1(i,j).*hn(i,j-1))+(beta2(i,j).*hn(i,j+1))+(beta3(i,j).*hn(i-1,j))+(beta4(i,j).*hn(i+1,j))) ./ (beta1(i,j)+beta2(i,j)+beta3(i,j)+beta4(i,j)));
    % Impermeable Edge Boundary Conditions 
    h(:,1) = ((beta2(i,1).*hn(i,2))+(beta3(i,1).*hn(i-1,1))+(beta4(i,1).*hn(i+1,1))) ./ (beta2(i,1)+beta3(i,1)+beta4(i,1))
    h(:,nx1) = h(:,nx1-1); 
    % Pressure at Inlet/ Outlet of flow
    h(1,:) = 0; %pressure at exit (atm, 0mm)
    h(ny1,:) = InletPressure; %pressure at entrance (mm)
end
```

Error Code produced:

```
Unable to perform assignment because the indices on the left side are not compatible with the size of the right side.

Error in SORMethodV4 (line 85)
    h(:,1) = ((beta2(i,1).*hn(i,2))+(beta3(i,1).*hn(i-1,1))+(beta4(i,1).*hn(i+1,1))) ./ (beta2(i,1)+beta3(i,1)+beta4(i,1))
```

Above equation is the matrix equation before Successive Over Relaxation was applied which gives the first h(i,j) line.
[image: Matrix Equation]

[image: Boundary 1 Equation]
Boundary 1 equation.

Comment: You can write one bit of code for the first column (`h(:,1)`), and a separate bit of code for all the other columns (`h(:,2:end)`). I'm not sure where the problem is for you. In your code, you index `h(i,j)`, but I don't see `i` or `j` defined anywhere. You probably intend to loop over both `i` and `j` inside the loop over `it`, though you can do this computation without loops. Since your equations are just weighted additions of neighboring elements, you could use `conv2` to do the heavy lifting.

Comment: It seems that there are several issues in your code. First, you haven't defined the loop indices i and j. Second, the assignment of the values for the first column of h is missing the loop indices. To fix these issues, you need to add nested loops for i and j indices, and make sure to use these indices while updating the h matrix.